# Derivative of moment generating function does not obey chain rule

Tags: probability, statistics, moment-generating-functions

I'm reading my book in the part about the moment generating function, and that's how it says to take the derivative in respect to $t$. Why the derivative goes inside? Why the chain rule is not used here?

[image]

Comment: By writing the expected value in a explicit way, i.e. as an integral, you are simply stating that $$\frac{d}{dt}\int g(x,t)\,dx = \int \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(x,t)\,dx, $$ also known as *differentiation under the integral sign*.

Comment: In other terms, $\mathbb{E}$ and $\frac{d}{dt}$ are linear operators, hence you may prove the identity above (please, use MathJax, you are a user with a reputation >1k now) by just exploiting the linearity of the expected value and the definition of derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: What is $\frac{d}{dt}\int_{a}^{b} e^{tx}f(x) dx$?

Comment: That's $\int_a^b xe^{tx}f(x)\ dx = E[xe^{tx}]$, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right!